# How separate one job to two smaller parts with using bus chain?

Tags: laravel, cron, jobs

I've got questiong about cron and job. My cron is running too long cause there is too much data. How is possible to separate the code to two smaller tasks. Maybe first task can proccess data, save them somewhere and next task will do compare bewteen them ? This task shoul do that it will log just pricelists which has different tax vat inside one purchase. This is my first experience witch chaining and docs didnt help me much. I will be glad for any advice :)

This is my job

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\Purchase;

use App\Models\Purchase;
use App\Jobs\Nodes\SendMail;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;

class VatValidation implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable;


    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $purchases = Purchase::get();

        $errors = [];
        foreach ($purchases as $purchase) {
            $purchaseGroups = $purchase->purchasegroups()->get();

            if (!$purchaseGroups) // Purchase has no purchase groups
                continue;

            $purchaseGroupsTaxes = [];

            // cycle thru pricelists
            foreach ($purchaseGroups as $purchaseGroup) {
                $pricelists = $purchaseGroup->pricelists()->where('ordered', true)->get();

                if (!$pricelists)
                    continue;

                $purchaseGroupPricelistsTaxes = [];

                foreach ($pricelists as $pricelist) {

                    if (empty($pricelist->tax))
                        continue;

                    $taxWithoutDotComma = str_replace(['.', ','], '', $pricelist->tax);

                    array_push($purchaseGroupPricelistsTaxes, $taxWithoutDotComma);


                    if (count(array_unique($purchaseGroupPricelistsTaxes, SORT_REGULAR)) > 1)
                        // Log::info("Different taxes found for", ["pgroup" => $purchaseGroup, "pricelists" => $pricelists, "taxes" => $purchaseGroupPricelistsTaxes]);
                        array_push($errors, "Different taxes found for", ["pgroup" => $purchaseGroup, "pricelists" => $pricelists, "taxes" => $purchaseGroupPricelistsTaxes]);
                    else
                        array_push($purchaseGroupsTaxes, $taxWithoutDotComma); // Taxes are same we need just one value
                }

            }

            if (count(array_unique($purchaseGroupsTaxes, SORT_REGULAR)) > 1)
                Log::info("Different taxes in purchasegroups found for", ["purchase" => $purchase->name, "taxes" => $purchaseGroupsTaxes]);
                array_push($errors, "Different taxes in purchasegroups found for", ["purchase" => $purchase->name, "taxes" => $purchaseGroupsTaxes]);

        }

    }



}
```

And this is cron

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs\Crons;

use Throwable;
use App\Models\Purchase;
use App\Jobs\Nodes\SendMail;
use App\Models\Purchasegroup;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use App\Jobs\Traits\cronTrait;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use App\Jobs\Purchase\VatValidation;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldBeUnique;

class purchaseVatValidationCron implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels, cronTrait;

    private $cronID;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(int $cronID = null,)
    {
        $this->cronID = $cronID;

        $this->queue = 'longRunning';
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        VatValidation::dispatch()->onQueue('longRunning');


    }


    public function failed(Throwable $exception)
    {
        $this->saveLog($this->cronID, $exception->getMessage(), 'error');
        Log::error($exception->getMessage(), ["VatValidationCron error"]);
    }


}
```

I am expecting that somebody more experienced will give me some advice how to solve the problem.

Comment: its much better if you update your `VatValidation` job, use DB Facades and chunk that main Purchase, then instead doing a lot of foreach, use join on all those tables you need

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting your job, you should optimize it properly and make sure it uses as little memory as possible, I can't imagine how much memory your job would eat with all those loops that calls `get` via Eloquent.

You can use [DB Facades Query](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/database#running-queries) with right join (based on how you filter/skip them on your loop), Im not sure about your actual table structure and relationship, but you can do a query like below. that [chunks](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#chunking-results) the result, its also better to put the errors in cache so you can easily check it anytime and from anywhere in your application

```
public function handle() {

    // this just a made-up example base on how you do your loops, 
    // you need to update this query properly base on your table name and table relationship
    DB::table('purchases')
        ->rightJoin('purchase_groups as pg', 'purchases.id', '=', 'pg.purchase_id')
        ->rightJoin('price_lists as pl', 'pg.id', '=', 'pl.purchase_group_id')
        ->where('pl.ordered', true)
        ->whereNotNull('pl.tax')
        ->chunk(100, function (Collection $purchases)  {

            $errors = Cache::get('purchases_errors') ?? [];

            foreach ($purchases as $purchase) {
                // your logic here, 
                // all data from 3 tables would be on purchase var
                $errors[] = 'new error';
            }

            Cache::put('purchases_errors', $errors, now()->endOfDay() );
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you just need distinct tax values per `PurchaseGroup` without real need for any other data, so let's simplify that. This will solve `n+1` performance problems and clean the code up a bit.

```php
$purchaseGroupQuery = PurchaseGroup::whereHas('purchase')
    ->whereHas(['pricelist' => function ($query) {
        return $query->where('ordered', true)->whereNotNull('tax');
    })->with(['pricelist' => function ($query) {
        return $query->selectRaw("REPLACE(
            REPLACE('tax', ',', ''), '.', ''
        ")->groupBy('tax');
    });
```

Now let's optimize the code a bit further by using `->chunk` to free up memory every `x` iterations (x being 25 at this point).

```php
$purchaseGroupQuery->chunk(25, function ($chunks) {
    foreach ($chunks as $purchaseGroup) {
        $purchaseGroupTaxes = $purchaseGroup->pricelists->pluck('tax');

        // $purchaseGroupTaxes is now an array of unique tax values for the purchaselists within the given purchasegroup.
    }
});
```

The optimizations above have:

1. removed the need for nested `n+1` queries by calling additional relationships in a loop
2. removed the need to check if relationships exist or are empty within the loop
3. formatted the `tax` value ahead of time for you
4. ensured that the values returned are `unique` to each `$purchaseGroupTaxes`
5. freed memory up between chunks to avoid exhausting our runner.

Comment: Problem with that i am not getting value of pricelist for purchasegroup